# IOError: invalid Python installation .../config/Makefile (No such file or directory)

Tags: python, macos, unix

After updating from OS X 10.8.3 to 10.8.5 and XCode my python installation stopped working. This is the output when I try to execute python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 420, in get_config_vars
_init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 288, in _init_posix
raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

I installed python separately (not the one that came with OS X) and hope to use that installation, how do I fix this? I have a bunch of virtualenv stuff setup and I don't know if that will break if I reinstall python so I'm hesitant to reinstall python.

Comment: Judging by the path, you used Homebrew to install Python. Did you try *reinstalling* Python with Homebrew yet? `brew uninstall` followed by a `brew install` perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by Martijn

`brew uninstall python`

The issue was that homebrew installed python and messed with my paths.